# Difference between nsswitch, nslcd and sssd?

Tags: sssd, nsswitch

I'm trying to configure sssd instead of nslcd for my Rhel system, and then I came across `nsswitch`.
What's the difference between these three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nsswitch` config file define the availability and order of querying name services (for hosts, users, groups, etc)

`sssd` manage access to remote directories and authentication mechanisms. It is extensively use to for authentication from AD

`nslcd` do LDAP queries for **local** processes based on a simple configuration file.

Generally speaking they do not have much in common.